# Optimizing Riddick Build

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization

For my new party I started playing [Jeff Gomez's Natural Killer build](http://zenithgames.blogspot.de/2014/01/natural-killer-ranger-build.html). But now at level 2 having the knowledge that everybody else is powergaming I would like to know if anyone has ideas getting the natural killer more deadly. So my goal is a damage optimization, the damage curve should be very good between level 7 and 12 since we usually don't play high levels but if it is very good before that I wouldn't have any problems with it! Since I am already at Level 2 the Class (Ranger) and Race (Human) was chosen already as well as the TWF at level 2 and the Kukris I have got from the GM. I got the Double Slice feat for free. Allowed is everything you can find on [the Pathfinder SRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/).

My personal buy is:

Str: 18
Dex: 16
Con: 14
Int: 8
Wis: 12
CHA: 7

I try to play a kind of [Riddick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riddick) character. I am chaotic neutral.

In case the link above is not working I give you backbone information about it here:

Feats:

1. Piranha Strike, Surge of Success
2. Bonus Feat: Two Weapon Fighting
3. Double Slice
4. —
5. Hunter's Trick (Vengeance Strike), Dodge
6. Bonus Feat: Improved Two weapon Fighting
7. Hunter's Trick (Second Chance Strike), Two-Weapon Defense
8. —
9. Hunter's Trick (Chameleon Step), Improved Critical (Wakizashi)
10. Bonus Feat: Greater Two-Weapon Fighting
11. Hunter's Trick (Deft Stand), Critical Focus
    12.
12. Hunter's Trick (Surprise Shift), Lunge
13. Bonus Feat: Two-Weapon Rend
14. Hunter's Trick (Rattling Strike), Blinding Critical
15. —
16. Hunter's Trick (Distracting Attack), Staggering Critical
17. Bonus Feat: Quick Draw
18. Hunter's Trick (Tangling Attack), Stunning Critical

Traits:

- Reactionary: +2 to initiative.  Everybody loves initiative.
- Carefully Hidden: +1 to Will saves (and a minor additional bonus)

How the levels look, assuming no magic gear and 20 pt buy:

- Level 1: Attacks with one Wakizashi at +6 (18-20/x2) for d4+4. +8 (15-20/x2) for d4+6 against one enemy a day.  5 Skills, 13hp, 19/13/16AC.  Saves 4/5/1.
- Level 8: Attacks at +12/+12/+7/+7 (15-20/x2) for d4+5.  +16/+16/+11/+11 (15-20/x2) for d6+9 against 3 enemies a day. 40 skills, 76 hit points, 21/14/17AC.  Saves 8/9/3.
- Level 12:  Attacks at +17/+17/+12/+12/+7/+7 (15-20/x2) for d4+6. +23/+23/+18/+18/+13/+13 (15-20/x2) for d4+12 against 4 enemies a day. 60 skill points, 112hp.  21/14/17AC.  Saves 10/11/5. (DPR: 78 against 4 average CR 12 enemies per day).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. So as your build already has a lot of set feats and such that you have to take we want to build upon that instead of trying anything new. So let’s take a look at feats and magic weapon enchants that effect critical hits or ways to free up any feats.

Not all of these options are possible for your exact build but I will add them for anyone in the future who wants to improve the build and has different stats than yourself.

## Feats

It might be a little late as you have already taken it but the exotic weapon proficiency feat was not required unless you have a RP reason for the wakazashi. Kukri has the same crit range, they do deal less damage at a d4 though. The base weapon damage won't make up much of your damage in the long run though and it would allow you to dedicate your first feat to something more useful. You might ask your DM if he would allow you to use the downtime retraining rules located [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/more-character-options/retraining).

#### [Butterfly’s Sting](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/butterfly-s-sting-critical)

Prerequisite [Combat Expertise](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/combat-expertise-combat), INT 13

Depending on your team you might also consider this feat as it allows your character to give up his crit to deal normal damage but the next ally to hit with a physical attack auto crits. So your big barbarian friend can deal massive amounts of damage if he has a low crit range weapon but a high crit modifier.

#### [Surge of Success](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/racial-feats/surge-of-success-human)

Prerequisite: Human

Following the theme of using your high crit chance this feat gives you a +2 on a single attack roll, saving throw, skill check, or ability check of your choice before the end of your next turn if you crit or roll a 20 on a saving throw.

## Equipment Enchantment

As you are after damage increase I will be focusing on magic weapon enchantments.

[Magic Weapon page for reference.](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons)

#### [Speed](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/speed)

Speed is a +3 enchant.

Speed is one of the more common enchants that players use. It grants an extra attack for each weapon it is on. So as your character dual wields that would be an additional 2 attacks at the character's highest BAB each round.

#### Element Burst

Again following the Crit theme the element burst enchants. Each is a +2 enchant

There are four of these types [Flaming](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/flaming-burst), [Icy](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/icy-burst), [Corrosive](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/corrosive-burst), and [Shocking](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/shocking-burst) each of them auto adds 1d6 of their element to all of your attacks. And when you crit they deal an additional 1d10 damage. The cool thing about these enchants is they can stack! So you can have a Flaming Burst, Corrosive Burst weapon that deals normal damage +1d6 fire +1d6 acid on normal strikes and when you crit it becomes Normal crit damage +1d6 fire +1d6 acid +1d10 Fire +1d10 Acid.

Comment: Hi! First off, thanks for your posting! That was of great help. I already got the Surge of Success feat, that was a great hint! Unfortunately my build is a low Int one so I couldnt use Butterfly's Sting.
I am still looking for a proper substitute feat for dodge and Double Slice feat. I already changed Weapon Focus for Piranha Strike and Exotic Weapon Focus Wakazaki to Surge of Success (I am using Kukris now).
Any Ideas on the best Spells and maybe better racial traits for that build would be awesome too. (I adjusted my question)

Answer (score -2):

Probably too late but for 10 k you can get an opal Ioun stone that if socketed gives you weapon focus and proficiency with a wakisashi.  Also if you pick up weapon versatility you won't have to worry about s/b/p DR.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE.  We work a little different from most forums, please see our help center.  Specifically, answers are meant for complete answers to the question asked. Once you've done that a while and earned some reputation, you'll be able to add comments to suggest additions to existing answers.